# C - Signedness when adding raw bytes

Tags: c, bit-shift, signed

I have sensor data in a uint8_t array which are signed (when concatenated to a 16 Bit value).
Now, I want to average the values over N cycles, such that I have to add them into a larger than int16_t value, i.e. a int32_t value.

```
int32_t val_x = 0 

//...

//do this n times when data is received, dataReceived is a uint8_t array
val_x += ((int16_t)dataReceived[3] << 8) | dataReceived[4];
```

But I have the feeling that this might cause errors. Assume I have a value of -1 (0xFFFF) and add it to a 32Bit signed value, it will interpret it as a positive value, right? Or does the compiler know, that when I cast to int16_t that this is a negative value and will represent it in the int32_t variable val_x as 0xFFFFFFFF? Do I have to do on more cast on the total value like

```
val_x += (int16_t)(((int16_t)dataReceived[3] << 8) | dataReceived[4]);
```

I program on a 16Bit (or possibly 24Bit with some always-zero-bits) (PIC24F from Microchip).
I hope you get the problem I am having. I'm a little lost by such a seemingly trivial problem...

Comment: Doing bitwise operations on signed numbers is generally a bad idea. And converting an unsigned value outside the signed range to signed causes implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: If you're lost, it's because you have mixed up a lot of different, unrelated and irrelevant parts. Start by isolating the parts you don't understand. Don't mix in the `val_x +=`-part, remove the `| dataReceived[4]`-part, replace `dataReceived[3]` with a scalar variable of the type you actually care about. Can you understand your problem *then*?

Comment: Yes, but this is the way the sensor puts out data. I have to work with it as is...

Comment: @EOF I am not sure what you mean. I think about it and hope you could walk me through it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(int16_t)dataReceived[3] << 8`, the `uint8_t` `dataReceived[3]` is converted to `int16_t`. This conversion operates by value; the bits representing it are irrelevant. Since all `uint8_t` values are representable in `int16_t`, the result is a value from 0 to 255, inclusive. In the case you ask about, the value is 255.

Then the *integer promotions* are performed on the left operand of `<<`. If `int` is 16 bits in this C implementation, then either `int16_t` is an alias for `int` or it is converted to `int`. (Exception: If the C implementation does not use two’s complement for `int`, the behavior is more complicated. However, this answer will not go into that.) Then the shift operation is performed. Shifting 255 left 8 bits mathematically yields 65,280. However, this is not representable in a 16-bit `int`, so the behavior is undefined, per C 2018 6.5.7 4.

If `int` is wider than 16 bits, then the integer promotions promote `int16_t` to `int`, the shift does not overflow, and the result is some value in 0 to 65,280, inclusive, that is a multiple of 256.

Then ORing in `dataReceived[4]` merges its bits into this value. The result is a value from 0 to 65,535, inclusive.

Then the cast to `(int16_t)` is applied. If the value is 0 to 32,767, it is the result. Otherwise, the value cannot be represented in `int16_t`. Then the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised, per C 2018 6.3.13. GCC and Clang define the result to wrap modulo 2<sup>16</sup>, so this will produce the result you desire. Other compilers might not produce the result you desire.

If `int` is 16 bits, you could avoid the overflow in shifting by casting `dataReceived[3]` to `int32_t` instead of to `int16_t`. Then the integer promotions will not change it, and the `int32_t` value will be shifted.

However, since we still need to deal with the overflow in the final conversion to `int16_t`, there is another method:

```
uint16_t tu = (uint16_t) dataReceived[3] << 8 | dataReceived[4];
int16_t  ti;
memcpy(&ti, &tu, sizeof ti);
val_x += ti;
```

This:

- Converts `dataReceived[3]` to `uint16_t` so the shift will not overflow.
- Completes the shift and merge and stores the result in a temporary `uint16_t` object.
- Copies the bits of the `uint16_t` object into an `int16_t` object to reinterpret them as a 16-bit two’s complement integer.
- Adds the integer to `val_x`.

The following code is effectively the same and avoids the named temporaries but may be less familiar and harder to read for novice C programmers:

```
val_x += (union { uint16_t u; int16_t i; }) { (uint16_t) dataReceived[3] | dataReceived[4] } .i;
```

Comment: Did you type the answer before I asked the question, like, just in case? :) Ok, give me a moment

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I got it now (had to google integer promotion).  So it depends on architecture and compiler, right? And, as I use int32_t as final type I want my data in, the two's complement is "padded as needed" in the new, larger type: 0xFFFF -> 0xFFFFFFF in case I add int16_t to the int32_t variable? If I added 0xFFFF typed as a uint16_t, I would get 0x0000FFFF in the int32_t variable?

Comment: @jjstcool: You do not need to think about “padding bits” when an `int16_t` is added to an `int32_t`. Arithmetic in expressions is done by **values**. The bits are **representations** in memory, and they are irrelevant. If `val_x` is 93 and the thing you are adding to it is −1, then the sum is 92, period. It does not matter what bits are used to represent `val_x` or what bits are used to represent −1. The types only matter if the arithmetic overflows the representable values in the result type.

Comment: @jjstcool: If the bits 0xFFFF are in a `uint16_t`, then its value is 65,535, and that is what would be used in arithmetic. You do not want that, which is why it must be converted to `int16_t` (in a compiler that defines this conversion to wrap) or its bits must be reinterpreted as an `int16_t` (which can be done with the `memcpy` or the union methods I showed). The value those bits represent in an `int16_t` type is −1. So adding that `int16_t` to the sum adds −1 to it.

Comment: You mention the memcpy thing, wouldn't a simple cast do the job too? Or wait, no, because the value 65535 would not fit into the int16 type. I think I never had a problem doing this but now I wonder why.

Comment: @jjstcool: Casts of arithmetic types operate by values. The behavior upon overflow is implementation-defined. So you cannot rely on it unless you tie yourself to a specific compiler and verify its documentation says it provides the behavior you desire. In contrast, using `memcpy` or a union reinterprets the bits in the new type, and `int16_t` is defined to use two’s complement and `uint16_t` is defined to be pure binary, so you know what the bits will be and how they will be interpreted. That allows you to write portable code that does not depend on a particular compiler.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Should be `memcpy(&ti, &tu, sizeof ti);`, no?

Comment: @EricPostpischil This clears it up thanks. My takeaway: Casts operate by value, so don't think about Bits and Bytes when doing arithmetics. What happens when the values overflow the type by the typecast (as 65535 in a uint16_t cast to an int16_t) is compiler dependent. However, when doing "raw" operations on memory, like memcpy, binary values are manipulated regardless of their type. (e.g. to translate it to a more extreme example: 65000.0 (type float) cast to an int will be 65000, however a memcpy of a float to an int would make it a whole different value, is that correct?)

Comment: thanks! Last follow up: It is mandatory in my case to use Bit-OR instead of +, as I simply want to make a binary concatenation of the bits instead of interpreting the lower and the upper byte in the context of types, right? Thanks man, you guided me through this perfectly

Comment: @jjstcool: If there is no overlap between set bits in the two operands, then `+` and `|` produce the same results. In theory, `|` is a simpler operation, as each bit in the result is dependent on only the corresponding two bits in the operands, while each bit in the result of `+` depends on all bits to the right, since there may be carries. This means `|` requires less hardware to implement and less energy and/or time to execute. But, on common modern processors, both are beneath the  processor’s single-cycle time and basic processing, so there is rarely any observable difference.

Comment: After thinking about it, problems would only arise if I did a cast to int8_t of the lower byte, but as it is uint8_t, there will be no problems, regardless of that I have done a cast to int16_t of the high byte. My first intuition was, that if I mixed types that I would need to handle different cases , but as long as the low byte is a uint-type, there are no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do not be afraid to use inline functions to make code clearer:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define ALWAYS_INLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
#else
#define ALWAYS_INLINE
#endif

static inline ALWAYS_INLINE int16_t combineInt16(uint8_t *d)
{
    int16_t i16;
    memcpy(&i16, d, sizeof(i16));

    return i16;
}

int16_t average(uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{
    int32_t average = 0;

    for(size_t index = 0; index < size / 2; index ++)
    {
        average += combineInt16(data);
        data += 2;
    }
    return average / size;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GcEKoGeWM

Comment: I will read this tomorrow, need sleep now. Boy, I am learning more about C on my 5 day hobby project, then in 3years of work...

Comment: Ok, I looked at it now and at the core you do the same thing as the answer from Eric. You do a bitwise concatenation of the input bytes and interpret it as int16_t afterwards. Correct so far? Now, you do the inline thing, but I don't get the context in which this is relevant. I guess this might be faster? Could you elaborate on that a little? Thanks.

Comment: (In my context this is not applicable however, as I don't have an array of [Highbyte1,Lowbyte1, Highbyte2,Lowbyte2,...] as my original post might misleadingly suggest. I get an array of sensor data and this adding-procedure is done on every new input, but only two bytes in the array are actually x-vals, next to y and z vals and status data. The averaging is done in a global variable added with new data everytime an interrupt occurs)

Comment: @jjstcool it makes almost no difference. BTW for that running average is better - as you want simple low pass filter.

Comment: ok, so the main point in your post is the memcpy as a means of re-interpretation of data? The inline is for speed-reasons only? I am just trying to figure out what your point was to make it all inline